# Laravel 5 Routes - Group Domains from Rows in Database

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a web application that needs to be served on multiple domains. I'm running Laravel 5.1 for this.

In the `routes.php` file, **I'd like to be able to identify which domain the user found the page through, and if that domain is found in a list of useable domains, then pass them over to a particular controller**.

The following snippet is from my `routes.php`:

```
$temporaryDomainList = \App\Domain::select('domain')->where('status','=','1')->get()->toArray();
// This returns us a 2-d array, with the second dimension just being ['domain','whatever.com'] -
// we want ['whatever.com','whatever2.com'] so let's clean it up...
$domainList = [];
foreach ($temporaryDomainList as $uselessArray) {
    $domainList[] = $uselessArray['domain'];
}

Route::group(['domain' => $domainList], function ($domainList) {
    Route::get('/{linkName}', 'RetargetController@retarget');
    Route::get('/', function () {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
    });
});
```

At the moment I get an error [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to assign an array of domains to the group's `domain` attribute. You can't do that, the `domain` attribute is [expected to be a string](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing), not an array of strings. When the `RouteCollection` class tries to [concatenate it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L67) with another string, you get an:

> Array to string conversion exception

To fix this you should create the groups inside the `foreach`:

```php
$domains = \App\Domain::where('status', '1')->get()->pluck('email');

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    Route::group(['domain' => $domain], function () {
        Route::get('/{linkName}', 'RetargetController@retarget');
        Route::get('/', function () {
            abort(404);
        });
    });
}
```

I've also used [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck) to get a collection of `domain` values fetched from the database, since it's all that's needed here. Also for brevity, calling the `abort(404)` helper function does essentially the same thing as throwing the `NotFoundHttpException` exception.

---

As a side note, you might want to put the route registration in a [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers) since the `routes.php` file doesn't seem a good place to put the database logic.

Comment: Woohoo! That worked! I did have to change the `pluck()` compared to what you show here though: `$domainList = \App\Domain::where('status','1')->get()->pluck('domain')->all();` worked for me

Comment: Actually, this is not working as expected. If the user comes from a domain outside that list, they are still passed into that group.

Comment: The `get` is indeed needed to fetch the result set, but using `all` is redundant, because `pluck` returns a [`Collection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php) instance that can be iterated using `foreach` without the need to convert it to an array. As for the second problem, you'll need to provide some clear cases, and explain what's wrong in each.

Comment: I'd rather go the service provider route after all